# Call postgres function with array param in jooq

Tags: java, sql, arrays, postgresql, jooq

How can I pass array param in postgreSQL function in native SQL with jooq?

The name of function compiled dynamically and I want to call it in string:

```
dsl().execute(someFunction + "(?)", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

Functions take argument with type **integer[]**

I've found ugly solution:

```
dsl().execute(someFunction + "(string_to_array(?, ',')::INT[])", Joiner.on(",").join(1, 2, 3));
```

I am using jooq version 3.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't use string concatenation

Both of your attempts use string concatenation to produce the function call: `someFunction + "(?)"`. While you're probably in full control of these strings, there's always a slight risk of adding unnecessary:

- Syntax errors
- SQL injection vulnerabilities

Better use jOOQ's built-in templating mechanism:

```
dsl().execute("{0}({1})", DSL.name("someFunction"), bindValue);
```

The templating mechanism is documented here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/plain-sql-queryparts

#### Pass array bind variables

It's easy. Just pass the bind variable as an array (not a list) in Java. For instance:

```
dsl().execute("someFunction({0})", DSL.val(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is a better way. Of cause, I use only array of integers and function's names in code, that do not promote SQL injection.